# Easyapache 4 issue in using php handler dso

Tags: php, apache, centos

Hai im trying to configure php handler dso in centos server and im getting this error

```
[root@2 ~]# /usr/local/cpanel/bin/rebuild_phpconf --ea-php70=dso

ERROR: The ea-php70 PHP package does not support the dso Apache handler
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the DSO handler, you need to install the PHP package on cPanel.

Run the following command to install the PHP 7.0 package.

yum install ea-php70-php

Note: You can only use DSO as the handler for one version of PHP on your system. If you install more than one DSO package, you must uninstall all but one package, or else the handler will not function correctly.

Refer:
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA4/PHP+Handlers#PHPHandlers-DSO